# Azure Storage private Image Url

Tags: ios, azure, authentication, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have an iOS app where I can upload images and see them in a newsfeed. At the moment im playing with the storage system of Azure and it is no problem for me to up and download an Blob with Shared Access Signatures. But I don't want to download them every time instead I would like to have an url which i can show. 
What i do is:

```
AZSCloudBlobContainer *blobContainer = [[AZSCloudBlobContainer alloc] initWithUrl:[NSURL URLWithString:@"SASURL"]];

AZSCloudBlockBlob *blockBlob = [blobContainer blockBlobReferenceFromName:@"bla"];

[blockBlob downloadToDataWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error, NSData *data) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error in downloading blob");
    }
    else{
        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];
    }
}];
```

What i would like to do is:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"SASURL"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data cache:YES];
```

Basically, I just need a sasurl which would display an image in the browser. Or in other words I have to download every time the Blob and i would like to have something like bloburl + sas to access them directly without downloading them. Maybe its not possible this is why i ask?

Comment: I think you should use the Azure file storage rather then the blobs

Comment: @BrijRajSingh - Not sure why you made that suggestion, as Azure File Service (which actually uses blobs underneath) has no way of exposing URL's to individual blobs - it's an SMB interface. Shifting to Azure File Service won't help the OP at all.

Comment: So if I understand your question correctly, you want to display the image in the browser and currently the image is downloading on the local computer. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yeah you completely right. I have to download every time the Blob and i would like to have something like bloburl + sas to access them directly without downloading them. Maybe its not possible this is why i ask?

Answer (score 0):

You can not limit who can use a SAS-based blob URI. However: Private blob URI's, unless shared, are not discoverable by others (except by sheer coincidence).

To limit exposure, you may set a short time limit on the URI links (say, 10 minutes). At that point, even if a link *was* compromised, the exposure window would be very small.

SAS-generation is nearly-trivial, so you should be able to generate on-the-fly SAS-based URLs from your app's service tier <del>(or in the phone app itself)</del>, for your phone app to consume.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i think my question was not ask correctly. I edited it. May you now understand better my problem.

Comment: I read your edits. a SAS url pointing to an image will be equivalant to a non-SAS url pointing to an image (because the SAS is just a querystring following the base part of the url). Your edits don't tell me anything different, really...

Comment: @DavidMakogon I have edited your answer and deleted "on in the phone app itself". While one can certainly do it but is **strongly not recommended** as you would need account key to generate SAS and keeping the key in the app is certainly not the way to go.

Comment: @GauravMantri - that's fine. I wasn't attempting to promote client-side SAS generation, but I had no idea where the OP's code existed.